# Cannot establish an ActiveRecord connection in my ruby script

Tags: sql-server, ruby, activerecord

I'm attempting to establish an Active Record connection with my ruby script and I keep getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
        10: from ./main.rb:2:in `<main>'
         9: from /home/daveomcd/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
         8: from /home/daveomcd/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
         7: from /mnt/c/Users/mcdonaldd/Documents/Ruby Projects/nfl_ngs/config/initializers/initializer.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
         6: from /home/daveomcd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:60:in `establish_connection'
         5: from /home/daveomcd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:950:in `establish_connection'
         4: from /home/daveomcd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:190:in `spec'
         3: from /home/daveomcd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:203:in `rescue in spec'
         2: from /home/daveomcd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:203:in `raise'
         1: from /home/daveomcd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:203:in `exception'
/home/daveomcd/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/errors.rb:84:in `initialize': wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 2) (ArgumentError)
```

My files for connection are listed below, I'm not sure what I'm doing incorrectly.

```
require 'active_record'
require 'tiny_tds'
require 'rubygems'
require 'json'
require 'pp'
require 'yaml'
require 'base64'
require 'uri'
require 'net/http'
require 'openssl'
require 'byebug'

# commented out and hard coded while debugging    
#@dbconfig = YAML.load(File.read("./config/database.yml"))
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
    adapter: 'sqlserver',
    host: '10.xxx.xxx.xx',
    post: '1433',
    database: 'mydb',
    username: '***',
    password: '***'
)
```

Comment: what is the actual error? You left this part off of the stack trace. Also you need to require `activerecord-sqlserver-adapter` to use it `tiny_tds`  is not enough

Comment: @engineersmnky, thanks my issue was I didn't have the require for 'activerecord-sqlserver-adapater' If you would like to submit an answer in regards to that I'll mark it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ActiveRecord` connections require connections adapters to transform the SQL appropriately to suit the database AR is interacting with. `ActiveRecord` ships with a set of native adapters including "mysql2","postgres", and "sqlite3", however in this case you are using MSSQL (as indicated by `adapter: 'sqlserver'` in your connection configuration)  which will require an external adapter.

The external adapter in this case is the [`activerecord-sqlserver-adapter`](https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter) gem.

This can be installed using `gem install activerecord-sqlserver-adapter` and then you just need to require it in your file as you have done with the other gems.

While this gem has no explicit dependencies (outside of `ActiveRecord`) you will need to specify a connection mode (or use the default :dblib). Using the default is by far the easiest route (and I have never had any issues with it), however this mode does require the inclusion of the [`tiny_tds`](https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/tiny_tds) gem (which you have already required)

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you must install activerecord-sqlserver-adapter as our friend says. By default, ruby on rails come with sqlite. Try install rubymine IDE, it will help you configure a database using an interface. Look at below:

[Configuration screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9uQU.png)